# How can I convert typedview to array

Tags: asp.net, telerik, llblgen

I am trying to convert TypedView class from LLBlGen to array.I am trying to bind this array to RadComboBox from Telerik. I am using WCF service to bind an array to list. Please let me know if you have any ideas?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The telerik combo supports binding to WCF service - I dug up [this live sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/loadondemand/wcf/defaultcs.aspx), probably a good start for your case.